# how to handle openlayers draw polygon event

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

I have draw controls in my OpenLayers application like this.

```
    var drawControls = {
        polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(polygonLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon),
        box: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(boxLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon,{
            handlerOptions: {
                sides: 4,
                irregular: true
            }
        })
    };
```

I am activating this controls with activate function of control.

```
 var control = drawControls[selected.key];
 control.activate();
```

This draws polygon on map. But I could not access the events of this control. For example, on draw end event should give me a polygon or box.

Comment: The events, by which I think you mean the callbacks of the drawing controls (such as, featureadded) have nothing to do with the polygon/boxes being drawn. It is likely you have an error elsewhere. Without full code/working example in jsFiddle or similar it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using `featureadded` event of the control.

```
    // Add a polygon layer to which polygons will be drawn.
    var polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon Layer", {
        projection: "EPSG:4326"
    });
    map.addLayers([polygonLayer]);

    // Initialize the polygon editor.
    var polygonEditor = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(polygonLayer,
        OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon);
    // And its event listener when the feature is added.
    polygonEditor.events.register('featureadded', polygonEditor, function(evt) {
        // Here, you should see the geometry of the drawn feature in your console.
        var geom = evt.feature.geometry;
        console.log(geom);
    });
```

And a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gberginc/r9g1odce/).

Comment: thanks for your solution. I am asking questions like this because OpenLayers documentation page does not include clear information about events of objects. For example what are the DrawFeature object events. And what is the "options parameter" of constructure  of classes.

Comment: @bookmarker OL docs usually have the `events` section where events are listed. In this case, see http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/DrawFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature.events. Sometimes it is necessary to look into the code for params or just try it out a bit.